# regular expression: allow alphabets and a comma in between only

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want to let the user input their own town/city and country, so I want to allow alphabets and a comma only in between city and country, below is what I came up with but it doesn't work with the second expression

```
'/[a-zA-Z\s]\,[a-zA-Z\s]/'
```

the first one is imperfect, bcos it allow as many commas as you want to put in,

```
'/^[a-zA-Z\s\,]+$/'

if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s\,]+$/', $mem_town_city_country) || !preg_match('/[a-zA-Z\s]\,[a-zA-Z\s]/', $mem_town_city_country))
{
   $error = true;
   echo '<error elementid="mem_town_city_country" message="TOWN/CITY, COUNTRY - sorry, they appear to be incorrect."/>';
}
```

how can I allow one comma only?

also, not sure if this is too much - can I check the character input for the city, for instance at least 3, and at least 4 for the country?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close. Try this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s]+\,[a-zA-Z\s]+$/
```

For the number of characters requirement:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\s]{3,}\,[a-zA-Z\s]{4,}$/
```

Comment: by adding {3,} instead of plus you say that you want at least 3 characters (your requirements for city and country)

Comment: Also instead of a-zA-Z you can use \w

Comment: @Michael. \w will include underscores and digits.

Comment: Why the '\,' you don't need to escape the comma

Comment: @Michael. That is true. Escaping the comma is unnecessary, but it won't hurt either.

Comment: What about something like “Cañon City, Colorado”?  Almost every time you see somebody enumerate the 26 letters in upper and/or lower case, it’s a red flag that they’re doing something wrong. To match any letter, you have to use `\p{L}`. Welcome to the new millennium.

Answer (score 1):

Only allowing letters ,at least 1 letter needed , also comma allowed :

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[a-zA-Z]{1,}');

if (regex.test(query)) {    
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: How is this answering the question? Please, elaborate a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

So close!  In fact, the extra that you were asking for is the very fix this one needs:

```
'/[a-zA-Z\s]{3,}\,[a-zA-Z\s]{4,}/'
```

You had correctly defined the character class, but hadn't indicated how often it should be [repeated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php).

Comment: Again, `[a-zA-Z]` is a bad way to write `(?=\p{ASCII})\pL`.